# How are all the raise options calculated in poker software

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

I am writing a poker software and trying to figure out how the raise system works.

There are a few parameters at play when raising:

```
Blinds: Blinds being played at
Last Raise: Last raise a player made
Total Pot: Total pot in the middle
Min Raise: Min raise allowed to make
50% Raise: 50% raise option a player can make
100% Raise: 100% raise option a player can make
```

Let's give a few examples to what could these parameters be at any point in time:

```
Blinds:      125/250   125/250  100/200  60/120
Total Pot:     1875      1125    2100     1920
Last Raise:     500       750     600      480
Min Raise:      750      1250    1000      840
50% Raise:     1875      1875    2000     1680
100% Raise:
```

I collected these samples during my games, and can be inaccurate.
I can see how some of the values are calculated for example:

`Blinds` `125/250`, and `Total Pot` is `1875`, that means 125 SB 250 BB 500 Raise and 1000 two calls. So `Last Raise` was `500` that is 250 more so we can make minimum 250 more with a raise to `750`, that is `Min Raise`.

How are the 50% and 100% raise parameters are calculated?

One possible explanation might be:

<strike>50% Raise means, 50% of the total pot more of min raise. In the above example, total pot is 1875, 50% of which is ~950, 950 more of min raise 750, which makes 1700 roughly the expected amount. What do you think?</strike>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When raising, count the "called" part and the "bet" part as being two distincts components of the raise happening one after the other. So if you raise to 5 after 1 to call, you effectively first call 1 then bet 4 more.

A pot size raise is simply a raise where the amount bet is equal to the pot after the call. So if a pot is of size 1, player A bets 1 in it, player B would make a pot size raise if he "calls" 1 and then bets 1 + 1 + 1, raising to 4 total.

Similarly, a 50% pot size raise would be betting half the pot after the "call". So in facing 1 to call, 1 + half of (1 + 1 + 1), raising to 2.5 total.

If the blinds are 125/250 and someone raises to 500 :

- There is 875 in the pot, and the "call" part of the raise would be 500 more = 1375
- Making a pot size raise would be 500 + 1375 = 1875
- Making a half pot size raise would be 500 + 1375/2 = 1187.5

Comment: What if "call" part is for the big blind, it would be 250 more = 1125, Making a pot size raise would be 250 + 1125 then?

Comment: What about allin, how is it expressed?

Comment: @eguneys if there are only blinds the pot size raise is 3.5 blinds (1 + 2.5 pot after call). If there is 1 caller its 4.5 blinds. I don't understand your second question though. All-in is the size of the player stack ?

Comment: If there are two players. Small blind make a pot size raise (0.5 + 2 pot after call) is that correct?

Comment: Yes, in addition to its blind it would be raised to 3, 2 to call for BB

Comment: So after preflop pot is 2, pot size raise is (0 call + 2 pot) raised to 2 ?

Comment: We often say pot size **bet** when there is no previous bet or blind to call and as the name suggest its always the size of the pot, no need to calculate a phantom call for this one.